# How to add missing foreign key/entity? Save BreezeJs with JObjects

Tags: angularjs, foreign-keys, breeze, foreign-key-relationship

This is database first using entity frameworks 6 and lazy loading. 
I have the following class of device that is missing four foreign key ids:

```
public partial class Device {
    public int SolutionId { get; set; }
    public string SiteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SysId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SysType { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual DeviceModel DeviceModel { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
    public virtual SolutionApplication SolutionApplication { get; set; }
    public virtual SolutionType SolutionType { get; set; }
}
```

Missing Keys/Ids that are not generated but automatically got mapped as virtual objects:

```
DeviceModelId, DeviceTypeId, SolutionApplicationId, and SolutionTypeId
```

I want to save a new device using breeze but it is looking for the device type. I tried adding the deviceTypeId before saving:

```
newDevice.deviceTypeId = 5;
```

But it still doesn't get read and does not get saved.

```
[Error] Save failed: Entities in 'PortalEntities.Devices' participate in the 'FK_Devices_DeviceTypes' relationship. 0 related 'DeviceType' were found. 1 'DeviceType' is expected.
```

This is how my save statement in my breeze controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        return _repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
```

I checked what actually is getting passed as it attempts to do a save. The save bundled contained the following entity. BUT the device type which is a required field is not there, hence the error that its missing.

```
"entities": [
{
  "SolutionId": -1,
  "SiteId": "11111d2",
  "Name": "asdf",
  "SysId": 0,
  "SysType": null,
  "SerialNumber": null,
  "ParentId": null,
  "entityAspect": {
    "entityTypeName": "Device:#HtPortal.Data.Portal",
    "defaultResourceName": "Devices",
    "entityState": "Added",
    "originalValuesMap": {},
    "autoGeneratedKey": {
      "propertyName": "SolutionId",
      "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
    }
  }
}
```

Since the deviceTypeId did not work, so I tried adding the deviceType right before saving:

```
newDevice.deviceType = { id:5, name: 'Blue'}; //NOTE: This already exists in the devicetype table in the database
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'entityState' of undefined
```

**Using Breeze, How do I add this foreign entity so that I can save this new device?**

**Edit 1: This is my DeviceType Class:**

```
    public partial class DeviceType {
            public DeviceType() {
                this.Devices = new HashSet<Device>();
            }

            public byte Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `PascalCase`, to match the property on the Entity, viz `newDevice.DeviceType = { id:5}` ? - or should that be `{ DeviceTypeId:5}` if `DeviceType` follows your PK naming conventions

Comment: Yes, I've tried the `PascalCase`. It made no difference.

Comment: "is missing four foreign key ids". That sounds like a fait accompli. But why don't you just add them?

Comment: I don't want to add them because every time I update the EDMX, it will be deleted. If I add it to a separate partial class, it does not pick it up when getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the existing `DeviceType` object from your dbContext.

Something like:

```
using (YourDbEntities context = new YourDbEntities())
{
    Device newDevice = new Device();

    //whatever initialisation you need do....

    newDevice.DeviceType = context.DeviceTypes.Find(5) 

    // the above line assumes that id is PK for DeviceType and you want the entry 
    // with id==5 - if not, other ways such as DeviceTypes.Where(d=>d.Id==5).First() 
    // to find the object in your existing db will work too!

    context.Devices.Add(newDevice);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant using breeze, how do I add the foreign entity and save it. Added the edit.